# cassandra too many open files

Tags: file, sockets, cassandra

I used cassandra 0.6.5 on two-node (`A` and `B`) cluster.
`Hector` is used in Client side.

One node `A` always has `too many open files exception` after running some time.
I run `netstat` on the node.
It shows a lot of `CLOSE_WAIT` tcp connections.

It is the culprit of the exception.
However, what causes so many `CLOSE_WAIT` connections,
Is it Client side `Hector` problem?
Why the other node `B` does not have this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using netstat, try `lsof -n | grep java`. How many file descriptors are listed there (you can get a count with `lsof -n | grep java | wc -l`)?

[The datastax docs suggest you might be hitting a default file descriptor limit of 1024](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/troubleshooting/index#java-reports-an-error-saying-there-are-too-many-open-files). You can change that via ulimit or in /etc/security/limits.conf. Datastax suggests the following changes:

```
echo "* soft nofile 32768" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "* hard nofile 32768" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "root soft nofile 32768" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "root hard nofile 32768" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
```

The debian package sets the following values:

```
# Provided by the cassandra package
cassandra  -  memlock  unlimited
cassandra  -  nofile   100000
```

I would also strongly recommend that you upgrade to a more recent version of Cassandra.

Comment: I already set ulimit to 20,000. lsof shows there are over 20,000 file descriptors.

Comment: How many of those are network connections? `lsof -n -i | grep java | wc -l`

Comment: Seconded on upgrading to a later version - Cassandra is now at 1.0.7

Comment: I just checked. I reboot the machine in the morning. Now `lsof` shows that there are 7029 open files. From `netstat`, there are 6865 `CLOSE_WAIT` TCP connections. It will keep increasing until it reaches the threshold of 20,000

Comment: If you're going to stick with 0.6, at least upgrade to the latest release in that series (0.6.13).  I wouldn't be surprised if a fd leak on compaction existed in early 0.6 builds...  However, be warned that 0.6 is obsolete at this point and a lot of the newer documentation does not apply there.

Comment: I upgraded to cassandra 0.6.13. But still Have the problem. A lot Close_wait TCP connections when "too many open files" exception happens.