# Cassandra unable to start with error too many files open

Tags: cassandra, startup

Cassandra unable to start with error too many files open. (apache-cassandra-1.2.4)

error file contains:

```
ERROR 11:53:11,893 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/analysis.engine/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-ib-289887-Data.db (Too many open files)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.open(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:46)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedSegmentedFile.createReader(CompressedSegmentedFile.java:57)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.PoolingSegmentedFile.getSegment(PoolingSegmentedFile.java:41)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getFileDataInput(SSTableReader.java:976)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.<init>(SimpleSliceReader.java:61)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.createReader(SSTableSliceIterator.java:68)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.<init>(SSTableSliceIterator.java:44)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(SliceQueryFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(QueryFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:274)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:65)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1357)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1214)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1126)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.serializedColumnFamilies(DefsTable.java:274)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.loadFromTable(DefsTable.java:155)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadSchemas(DatabaseDescriptor.java:563)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:229)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:411)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:454)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/analysis.engine/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-ib-289887-Data.db (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:212)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.<init>(RandomAccessReader.java:67)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.<init>(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:75)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.open(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:42)
    ... 19 more
```

Please help me to find out the problem and it's solution.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049974/cassandra-too-many-open-files

Comment: That suggested duplicate is for a very old Cassandra question, but this is for a more recent version

Answer (score 0):

@N D Thokare

Do you use the new Java driver from datastax to connect to Cassandra ?

I had the same issue recently, and the reason was that I bootstrapped many Session at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use root permission and set:
ulimit -n 1000000